# Is there any other constitutional body represented in Autonomous Communities?

Tags: separation-of-powers, spain

In Spain,

- Autonomous Communities (A.C.) Presidents hold a *representation* of/from the State (every power of the State, ultimately deriving from popular citizen vote) in the A.C.<sup>[reference TBMA on demand]</sup>.
- Government Delegates hold a *representation* of/from the Government (/Administration) in the A.C.<sup>[reference TBMA on demand]</sup>.

Do Presidents of *Tribunales Superiores de Justicia* hold a *representation* of/from Justice in the A.C.?

**Any other constitutional body with a similar phrasing?**

What's it mean? What's it for?

Answer (score 0):

Not the lower house.

> [REGLAMENTO DEL CONGRESO DE LOS DIPUTADOS](//www.boe.es/buscar/act.php?id=BOE-A-1982-5196)
>    TITULO III DE LA ORGANIZACION DEL CONGRESO
>     CAPITULO PRIMERO De la Mesa
>      Sección I. De las funciones de la Mesa y de sus miembros
>       Art. 30.
>        1. La Mesa es el órgano rector de la Cámara y ostenta la representación
>        colegiada de ésta en los actos a que asista.

> [[...]](//www.boe.es/buscar/act.php?id=BOE-A-1982-5196)
>    TITLE III [...]
>     CHAPTER ONE [...]
>      Section I. [...]
>       Art. 30.
>        1. [...] will represent the House in events [...].